# Free Pascal: fast and efficient reading of files

Tags: freepascal, file-handling, file-read

Is there faster and more efficient way of reading of files than using AssignFile, Reset and Read (on Windows x86 and x64)? 
I need to grep (using TRegExpr) many text files for a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Two directions:

1. Keep using text, and to get the max out of assignfile c.s. use  [settextbuf](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/settextbuf.html) to increase the buffer size to say 8kb. (bigger values are possible, but don't really speed up anymore)
2. Otherwise you must craft your own text access using normal binary file access.